# INT_[MIN|MAX] limit macros vs numeric_limits<T>

Tags: c++

Is there any argument for using the numeric limits macros (e.g. `INT64_MAX`) over `std::numeric_limits<T>`? From what I understand `numeric_limits` is in the standard but the macros are only in C99 so therefore non-standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If C++, use `numeric_limits`, end of.

EDIT: Okay, per the comment by James, not "end of." - exceptions are templates and case labels. But, I cannot see a use for having a case label for either min or max, or a template for them, but I guess I've not seen all possibilities...

I guess my point is that the `numeric_limits` template is more useful beyond `max()` and `min()`...

Comment: Try it in a context where an integral constant expression is required.  Say instantiating a template, or in a case lable.  Or for smaller types , as an array dimension (`UCHAR_MAX + 1` is frequent).

Comment: @James, hmm.. okay, I'll edit for templates and case labels, not sure about array dimensions though...

Comment: Important note: since C++11 `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` is `constexpr`, so, the exception no longer hold.

Answer (score 20):

The other answers mostly have correct information, but it seems that this needs updating for C++11.

In C++11, `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()`, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`, and `std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest()` are all declared `constexpr`, so they can be usable in most of the same contexts as `INT_MIN` and company. The only exception I can think of is compile-time string processing using the `#` stringification token.

This means that `numeric_limits` can be used for case labels, template parameters, etc., and you get the benefit of using it in generic code (try using `INT_MIN` vs. `LONG_MIN` in `template<typename T> get_min(T t);`).

C++11 also brings a solution to the issue James Kanze talks about, by adding `std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest()`, which gives the lowest finite value for all types, rather than the lowest value for integer types and the lowest positive value for floating-point types.

Answer (score 10):

Pre C++0x, definitely.  `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` are integral constant expressions; `numeric_limits<int>::min()` and `numeric_limits<int>::max()` aren't.  `<climits>` is standard C++, and unless you're dealing with templates (where you don't know whether it's `int` or `long`), there's really no reason to bother with the overly complicated solution.  (Also: if you're writing templates, don't forget that `numeric_limits<int>::min()` and `numeric_limits<double>::min()` represent completely different attributes; if you want the minimum possible value, you'll need `numeric_limits<T>::is_integer ? numeric_limits<T>::min() : -numeric_limits<T>::max()`.)

Comment: I'd add that the integral constant expression argument only counts, if you want to use the values in templates.

Comment: @Xeo: That's not true. It also matters when you're initializing a class static.

Comment: @MSalters, ? you cannot initialize an integral class static without an integral constant?

Comment: You can, but then you'll need to define it outside your class.

Comment: @Xeo As a template argument, as the dimension of an array, as a case label, and possibly some other cases I've forgotten.  In general, the simple rule is to use the simple solution (`INT_MAX`, etc.) when you know the type, and the complex one (`numeric_limits`) when you don't.

Comment: Note that in some versions of GCC (at least 4.6 and 4.7), you may not get limit macros in C++ due to this bug (fixed for 4.8): http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52764

Comment: @TrevorRobinson This doesn't seem to affect `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN` (which are so widely used that any compiler where they were missing wouldn't stand a chance of being used).

Answer (score 5):

Although in C++11 the constants in `std::numeric_limits` are `constexpr` so that you can use them in templates etc., there's still at least one scenario when you *must* use macros from `<climits>`/`<cstdint>` instead. It's preprocessor. In C++, preprocessor is as limited as it is in C, so it can't use normal variables, be it a `const` or `constexpr` one. Much less so members of structures, and even less so templated structures. Thus you can't do the following:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <limits>

// Won't work!
#if std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() > std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()
// ...
#endif
```

Instead, you should resort to the following working (and more readable!) variant:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <climits>

// Works fine
#if SIZE_MAX > UINT_MAX
// ...
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

In certain contexts (e.g. `case` labels, non-type template parameters) a numeric constant is expected, and `numeric_limits` doesn't support this: `numeric_limits<int>::max()` is not a constant. In `case` labels, you have to use `INT_MAX` instead.

This is very annoying but i hear C++11 will fix this.