# Should I be using numeric_limits or C limit macros?

Tags: c++, c++11, numeric-limits

I'm new to SO and this is my first question, but I've read the rules and I hope that I won't break any of them.

I have recently started learning programming and have chosen C++ as my first language. Today I have reached a point where I need help to make a proper decision. I'm learning from a 6th edition of C++ Primer Plus and so far author have only introduced C macros and haven't said a single word about **numeric_limits** template ( at least I think it's a template ) about which I have learned from internet thanks to my curiosity.

So, now I'm a bit lost, because if I understood correctly **numeric_limits** are a modern way for checking the limits of C++ types thanks to its easy expandability. Furthermore AFAIK among the C macros there aren't definitions for C++11 types like char16_t.

While searching only thing I have found is [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579641/int-minmax-limit-macros-vs-numeric-limitst), but provided answers as helpful as they are, unfortunately they doesn't answer what is specifically interesting for me. Also they are mostly quite old actually.

Now, the specific question:

Basing on the needs for speed of code execution, safety and usefulness in future  ( I don't care that much about simplicity ) is it better idea to use those old C macros or should I stick to **numeric_limits** considering the aspects I have mentioned?

Please, forgive me any mistakes in my English. It's not my native language.

Comment: Your English is fine.

Comment: The accepted answer in the question you linked is still good advice.  Use `numeric_limits`.  If your compiler supports `C++11` fully, then most of `numeric_limits` functions are `constexpr` which increases their usefulness.

Comment: @PeteBecker thank you very much.

I'm using g++ 4.8.1 through MinGW as my compiler, which AFAIK mostly supports C++11, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For most code either C's macros or C++'s `std::numeric_limits` work fine. In C++03 there was an issue that the `min()` and `max()` members couldn't yield constant expressions but this problem is solved with C++11's `constexpr`.

Both approaches are fully type safe and I would be surprised if you could measure a difference between two versions of a program differing only in the way the type properties are obtained. The primary area where macros are not an alternative are templates: you need a fixed names for the templates entities and the macros just don't work like that (they are also expanded at the wrong time during compilation).

Personally, I always use `std::numeric_limits<T>`, mainly because I can use it in all of my code and I can remember the names better.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I needed. To be honest I think that `std::numeric_limits` are actually easier to get used to, because I don't need to learn names of all those macros. All I need to know are the names of the types, which I'm already comfortable with. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

While both DBL_MAX and std::numeric_limits::max() are perfectly fine (besides the latter is annoying long) you might not use the former when you want to change a value representation having a typedef:

```
struct X {
   typedef double Real; // may become float
};
```

Also, having templates you have to use std::numeric_limits.