# Maximum value that can be stored in an integer type in C++

Tags: c++, int

I have the following program in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    printf("range of int: %d to %d", SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX);
    int a = 1000006;
    printf("\n Integer a is equal to %d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is - How is `a` able to store an integer larger than the MAX limit?

Comment: `SHRT` stands for `short`.

Comment: in C++ you should use `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` anyway, as then you can be sure you're getting the limits of the right type. Also the answer is to use a `long long` which is guaranteed by the standard to be larger than an `int`

Comment: @YuHao the argument could be made that your edit was correct as `<limits>` is not guaranteed to include `<climits>` and the macros the OP is using are available in `<climits>` not `<limits>`. However what the OP should be using [`std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) is not available in `<climits>` hence me removing my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/climits and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits

`SHRT_MAX` is the maximum value for an object of type `short int`, but `a` is of type `int`, so the appropriate constant would be `INT_MAX`. A usual value for this on 32-bit systems would be 32767 ( 2¹⁵-1). You probably have a 64-bit system, where 2147483647 ( 2³¹-1 ) might be the upper bound.

Also, as pointed out in a comment above, you might also rather want to run

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "type\tlowest\thighest\n";
    std::cout << "int\t"
              << std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest() << '\t'
              << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

in some cases (see [INT_[MIN|MAX] limit macros vs numeric_limits<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579641/int-minmax-limit-macros-vs-numeric-limitst) ) to determine these values (code copied from reference page mentioned above).

On a side note, if for some reason the width of the integer types is relevant to your code, you might also want to consider looking at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint for fixed width integer types (see also [Is there any reason not to use fixed width integer types (e.g. uint8_t)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413521/is-there-any-reason-not-to-use-fixed-width-integer-types-e-g-uint8-t) for a discussion).

Comment: @Mgetz Thanks, I've added it to the answer, the page you provided is much nicer indeed (note to myself: don't always pick the first Google hit for reference purposes...)

Answer (score 2):

An integer type variable is a variable that can only hold whole numbers (eg. -2, -1, 0, 1, 2). C++ actually has four different integer variables available for use: char, short, int, and long. The only difference between these different integer types is that they have varying sizes

Your variable is of type int ( not short )

Minimum value for a variable of type short.

```
SHRT_MIN
–32768
```

Maximum value for a variable of type short.

```
SHRT_MAX
32767
```

Minimum value for a variable of type int.

```
INT_MIN
–2147483647 – 1
```

Maximum value for a variable of type int.

```
INT_MAX
2147483647
```

And `a` is able to store `1000006` , because

```
a = 1000006 <  2147483647
```

So there is not an issue  :)